# Calling malloc multiple times

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, malloc

What happens when you call malloc() multiple times on same variable? How should I free previously allocated memory? I am planning to use struct iovec to store data (so that I can send/write these chunks later). Before calling each malloc, I would like to save current reference to iovec array. After doing this, I will call malloc on same variable to get new memory block of fixed size. After it's exhausted, I will save it in iovec array and call malloc again and so on. Can I free iovec array later? Please let me know if this is the right approach or suggest any better alternative way?

Comment: Can you use `realloc` instead?. We need to see some code in order to help you

Comment: Please post your code, it's hard to tell what you mean. You can make an array of pointers, and save each allocation in one of the array elements. Then you can later loop over the array and free all of them.

Comment: @RoiHatam:  I don't want to call realloc. Because it seems very costly operation in this scenario.

Comment: You can't call `malloc` on "same variable". You can *assign* it's result to the same variable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. : Before I call malloc on same variable, I will save the reference in some array.

Comment: Good luck with that. What is the problem then?

Comment: What's wrong? I haven't started coding yet. I was just wondering whether this is the right way to do this? How should I free this array later? Can I loop over them free all of them later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like you're doing something like the following:

```
var = malloc( sizeof *var );
do_something_with( var );
vec[i++] = var;
var = malloc( sizeof *var );
```

If that's true, then this is okay (modulo error and sanity checks) - you're saving the reference to the previously allocated memory before overwriting `var`.  When you're done, you'd cycle through `vec` to `free` each element:

```
while ( i > 0 )
  free( vec[--i] );
```

If you're doing something like:

```
var = malloc( sizeof *var );
do_something_with( var );
var = malloc( sizeof *var );
```

then you have a problem - you've clobbered your only reference to the previously allocated memory, leaving you without any way to access or `free` it, leading to a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I am doing very similar to first approach. I am allocating fixed length buffer. Once it's full, save this reference and do malloc() again.

Comment: @mehtame026: then you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you @John..